# Migrate an umbraco v10.6.0 site from a web site to an appplication under a root web site

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog, umbraco-contour, umbraco-10

I have a request to migrate my umbraco v10.6.0 site from a web site to an application under a root web site. I am trying to make it work by first running my site in my local PC with my unbraco solution configured to run in my local IIS.

I know I have to first change my database in order to put my application name in my media path.

So far I have been able to get my site running under my application ex: http://localhost/MyUmbracoApplication. My problem is that I still got some URL pointing directly to the site and not to the application. For example, when I try to log to the back office, I get a 404 Not found for my UmbracoAPI http://localhost/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/authentication/IsAuthenticated which is missing "myUmbracoApplication" in the path.

I tried a lot of different setups by doing changes to my ApplicationVirtualPath, SiteName, UmbracoApplicationUrl, and other variables in my appsettings.json with no success. There is probably something wrong or missing in the way I configure my solution.

Would someone be kind enough to help me get in the right direction to make it work. Any income is already highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be this setting you are after? https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/configuration/hostingsettings#application-virtual-path -or maybe look here for tips (like making sure your parent app ignores the Umbraco path): https://our.umbraco.com/forum/developers/api-questions/64995-Setting-up-Umbraco-as-a-subsite-inside-another-Website-Virtual-Directory-converted-to-application-in-IIS

Comment: Hi Jannik, I have no web.config under my parent website that can interfere wit my application.  I tried making changes to my settings in the Hosting and WebRouting sections.  I tried various combinaisons of ApplicationVirtualPath, SiteName and UmbracoApplicationUrl variables with values / no values / full path or not without success.  I'm currently running in my own Localhost instance of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run umbraco in a (virtual) folder. Instead, host it as a new website in your IIS with

1. a different port, eg localhost: 44301 or
2. use local bindings in your IIS and add a "mysite.local" in your hosts file.

That being said, with modern Umbraco versions (v9 and later) the site runs perfect on your local machine in kestrel (instead of configuring everything in IIS). Also using IIS express is perfect for most websites.